# Updating MySQL record with imploded array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently attempting to update existing records within a MySQL database. Prior to the updated information being sent to the database, it is placed in an array, run through a validation function before using the implode function to enable me to insert the array into the database. This works fine when adding new users, but I am having difficulty using the imploded array for a UPDATE query.

Can I specify individual strings from the imploded array, so that I can SET username to the username string contained within the original array?

I currently have something like this which is giving me an SQL error - however, I never expected this to work as the SQL syntax is wrong.

```
public function editUser($array, $userID) {
    $edited = 'User Ammended';
    $array['password'] = $this->hashPassword($array['password']);
    $implodeArray = '"'.implode( '","', $array ).'"';
    $sql = ('UPDATE user (email, password, firstName, lastName, officeID, departmentID, managerID, roleID, username) WHERE userID=$userID VALUES ('.$implodeArray.')');
    mysql_query($sql,$this->_db) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
public function editUser($array, $userID) {
        $edited = 'User Ammended';
        $array['password'] = $this->hashPassword($array['password']);
        /*Assuming array keys are = to database fileds*/
        if (count($array) > 0) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value); // this is dedicated to @Jon
                $value = "'$value'";
                $updates[] = "$key = $value";
            }
        }
        $implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
        $sql = ("UPDATE user WHERE userID=$userID SET $implodeArray");
        mysql_query($sql,$this->_db) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: -1: This will break the query if there is anything in `$array` that needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Jon, read the question "run through a validation function before using the implode function to enable me to insert the array into the database" and please delete the down vote.

Comment: @Charlie: We don't know what the validation function does. I wouldn't give a -1 if the answer said "I am assuming everything will be already escaped".

Comment: @Jon, he is already assuming it in its question. His code is probably reduced to essential (notice the `$edited` variable not used) and he has already thought about inputs got escaped...

Comment: @Charlie: The data may have already been escaped (even though I would consider it *very bad* design to escape in the validation function!), or it may have not been. I downvoted because *assuming* is a bad idea when security and stability is at stake.

Comment: @Jon, the questioner didn't asked for that, he asked for another problem. You are giving downvotes for no reasons here and Karma will hit you...

Comment: Hi guys, just to clarify, the validation function escapes everything to ensure no malicious data is input.

Comment: @Charlie: Let's just say that I consider writing `mysql_` and not `escape_` in the same post a grievous sin and leave it at that. I am undoing the vote because there's no sense in fighting like children over something so trivial.

Comment: @JHamill, actually that function was wrong, check the new one out :)

Comment: @JHamill, just to know: Why did you delete the accepting of the answer? Have you encountered problems?

Comment: @Charlie, I implemented your original function and it did not work. I'll attempt the new one shortly.

Comment: @Charlie, I have implemented your edited code snippet, and I believe the fault is elsewhere in the code with regards to the $userID being empty. I am retrieving the $userID from $_GET['userID']; and when echoing $userID after selecting the user, the correct user ID is displayed, however, when I pass it to the editUser function and attempt to echo the $userID and kill off the rest of the script, the page is empty, leading me to believe their is a problem passing the variable to the function.

Comment: @JHamill, well, remember that you have to pass the edits first and then the userID like this `editUser($edits, $userID);`

Comment: @Charlie, thanks for your response. My edited data is stored in $array, which is passed along with $userID like so: $user->editUser($array,$userID);. When $userID is sent to the function it is populated with the correct value.

Comment: @Charlie, unfortunately it is not working. Here is the SQL error I am receiving. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE userID='' SET email = 'email@hotmail.co.uk', password = 'd41d8cd98f00b2' at line 1"

Comment: @JHamill, Well, it seems that $userID is empty. Could you please edit your question adding for a moment your entire script? I'll be glad to check it for you. (or even better: use http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Charlie, I have solved the issue, the problem was elsewhere in the code. I have used the code you provided and it has worked without problem. Thanks for your time with this.

Answer (score 1):

First off. Please stop using the mysql* functions. PDO has numerous significant advantages.

As for your specific issue:

This is not a valid MySQL statement:

```
UPDATE table (col1, col2) WHERE 1 VALUES('foo', 'bar')
```

You need to use something like:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'foo', col2 = 'bar' WHERE 1
```

Using PDO this could still make use of array input, as the PDOStatement::execute() method accepts an associative array of values, with the keys corresponding to placeholders in the SQL statement passed to PDO::prepare.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to focus on fixing the PHP embedded SQL syntax error here.

First, let's look at the legal syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Next, let's look at the broken form:

```
$sql = ('UPDATE user (email, password, firstName, lastName, officeID, departmentID, managerID, roleID, username) WHERE userID=$userID VALUES ('.$implodeArray.')');
```

Finally, since the array is already an ordered list (you're imploding it), let's repair and replace with something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user 
SET email = '$array[0]', 
password = '$array[1]', 
firstName = '$array[2]', 
lastName = '$array[3]', 
officeID = '$array[4]', 
departmentID = '$array[5]', 
managerID = '$array[6]', 
roleID = '$array[7]', 
username = '$array[8]' 
WHERE userID = '$userID.'";
```

I'm also assuming the input values are already escaped, filtered and checked.

UPDATE:
If possible in your environment/framework, use prepared statements.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP >= 5.3 for anonymous functions (otherwise, the callback would have to be written as a free function or as a string):

```
$implodeArray = implode(',',
    array_map(
        function($item) { return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($item)."'"; },
        $array));
```

**Please** do not **ever** put things in queries that have not been escaped first!

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your information is coming from a form (method=POST) where the field names of the input boxes are the same as the field names in the code, and it has a hidden input 'userId' that determines the 'where' clause.

It uses PDO and binding parameters.

```
$query = "update users set ";

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if($key != 'userId') {
    $inputs[] = " $key = ? ";
    $valueArray[] = $value; }
    }
$query .= implode( ',', $inputs );

$query .= " where id = " . $_POST['userId'];

$sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($valueArray);
```